# Disambiguation of limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let's say we're dealing with a definite integral that doesn't use common variables:

$$\int_0^1 a^2b^2\,da$$

Because the integral is taken with respect to $a$, it's clear that $a$ is the independent variable, and we'll assume that $b$ is a constant, taking us to:

$$\left.\frac{a^3b^2}{3}\right|_0^1$$

Because of the previous step, I remember that I substitute $1$ and $0$ for $a$, but what if I hadn't known that, or I just wanted to be clear in my work? How would I rewrite this? $\left.\frac{a^3b^2}{3}\right|_{a=0}^1$ or possibly $\left.\frac{a^3b^2}{3}\right|_{a=0}^{a=1}$?

Comment: Under the assumption that $b$ is not a function of $a$, then your procedure and notation to designate the limits are fine.  However, $b$ could be a function of $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sometimes written things like this in the form
$$
\left. \frac{a^3 b^2} 2 \right|_{a:=0}^{a:=1}
$$
or as
$$
\left. \frac{a^3 b^2} 3 \right|_{a=0}^{a=1}.
$$
Your third notation also seems perfectly comprehensible.